# Copying multiple filtered pivot tables to multiple powerpoints

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate making PowerPoints so I can avoid making 50 per month. I have my code set up so it goes into my folder and opens all the necessary powerpoints. While it is opening the powerpoints, it filters my pivot table, copies, and pastes into the correct file.

However - when I run the Macro - it skips the first market

ex: when the macro is run - this is my result

Market1 Pivot pastes to no where

Market2 pivot pastes to  Powerpoint 1 & Powerpoint 2

Market3 Pivot pastes to Powerpoint 3

I am assuming it has something to do with my "On Error Resume Next" line but unsure how to fix this. 
Here is my code:

```
'Open Powerpoints

Set pptapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptapp.Visible = True

market = Array("market1", "market2", "market3")

For i = 0 To UBound(market)
    'open Powerpoints
    Set pptpres = pptapp.Presentations.Open("Powerpoint Folders")
    Set pptslide = pptpres.Slides(7)
    'update pivot tables
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ws1.Activate    
    Set Tradepivot = ws1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")  
    With Tradepivot.PivotFields("Market")
        On Error Resume Next
        For z = (0 - 1) To (.PivotItems.Count)
            .PivotItems(.PivotItems(z).Name).Visible = False
            .PivotItems((market(i)) & " Market").Visible = True    
            Tradepivot.TableRange1.copy
        Next z

        pptslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject
        pptapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")    
    End With        
Next i
```

Comment: Can you share your PivotTable, especialy your `PivotFields("Market")` values ?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot - but for example sake we can say states: so for the 3 market example I gave - New Jersey, Washington, and Texas

Comment: I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `For z = (0 - 1) To (.PivotItems.Count)` loop, what are you trying to do there ?

Comment: when I was originally running the macro - it was skipping the first markets pivot table and pasting either nothing or market 2's pivot table in so I was trying different variations of (-1) to see if that was the issue

Comment: I'll write some code down, not sure if it's the full answer, but test it and let me know if it helped

Comment: I took (z-1) out and its works...sometimes. Some times it returns all to the proper powerpoint but sometimes it skips on or just crashes powerpoint..any suggestions?

Comment: will do - thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try the section of code below, see if it helps you:

```
Dim PvtFld As PivotField
Dim PvtItm As PivotItem

With Tradepivot
    Set PvtFld = .PivotFields("Market")
    PvtFld.ClearAllFilters
    For Each PvtItm In PvtFld.PivotItems
        If PvtItm.Name = market(i) Then
            PvtItm.Visible = True
        Else
            PvtItm.Visible = False
        End If                
    Next PvtItm
    Tradepivot.TableRange1.Copy

    pptslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject
    pptapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
End With
```

Comment: Getting a runtime error 1004 "unable to set visible property of pivot item class" on "PvtItm.visible = false". thank you though1 gave me another look at it, I don't want to bother you with this any more but if anything else comes up, please feel free to comment

Comment: @messi1335 let me know if you were able to figure it out, even though without seeing some kind of data sample (even with made-up data) it's almost impossible to debug

Comment: I understand, unfortunately I am under a NDA but I definitely will